# ASPX File Contents Vary - NotePad vs SP Designer (True Newbie)

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have inherited a MOSS 2007 site created by somebody else and I am trying to understand some things about it.  In order that I don't break an existing page, I copied it in Windows Explorer to a new file name in the same folder.  Opening the copied file in SP Designer, it does not look the same as the original file does in SPD.  I notice that the original file has different code contents when viewed in NotePad (off the server file system) than it does when opened in SPD.  What is going on here?  Also, does anybody feel like recommending a particular online MOSS 2007 learning experience?  I know MOSS is outdated by a couple of releases, but I'm constrained to it for the time being.